# How to show a client-side message with Java JSF/Tobago?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, messagebox, tobago

I have a web application created with JSF and Tobago. The user types some date into a sheet and clicks a button (all within one sheet-row). Now my java class checks whether the data is correct or not. In case there are some problems, I would like to show up something like a messagebox containing the errormessage.

I cannot use something like JDialog, since this would happen only server side. Every user independently of his location needs to get the message. I thought about setting the error information into a databean and having my jsp show up the message after reloading. But how can I achieve this? Is there something like a tag which can be used for this? Or can I use the "confirmation" facet for this? But how would I start it without having the user to do something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you familiar with `h:message` / `h:messages` ? Or do you really, really want a dialog/alert?

Comment: Bozho: Currently we are not using Richfaces, but if it can provide a solution, it might be a point to discuss ;)

BalusC: If I am right h:message is for having something like a little red dot ans some error description next to the validated field, correct? Case true, it wont fit for me since the fields to validate are within a sheet. How should this work? And yes,... I would really, really like to have something popping up to have the users attention ;)

Comment: Ah OK. Well, it may be good to know you can just style the `h:message` and `h:messages` the way you want using CSS. It has `style` and `styleClass` attributes as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<rich:modalPanel id="messagePanel">
     <h:outputText value="#{yourValue}" />
</rich:modalPanel>
```

(see the [richfaces demo app](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/modalPanel.jsf?c=modalPanel&tab=usage) for how to add more features to the modal panel)

Then within your "sheet":

```
<a4j:support action="#{bean.yourValidationAction}" 
    event="onclick"
    oncomplete="if(#{facesContext.maximumSeverity != null}) 
    {#{rich:component('messagePanel')}.show()}" />
```

this will show a message if you add a faces error message.

(have in mind that the `event` attribute can be any of the on* attributes (events) of the control, where the `<a4j:support>` is nested)

Comment: Hm, it's a good idea and the demo app shows that this would be exactly what I need, but I forgot about the renderer problem... Tobago does not support different renderers :/ Seems as if I must use alert boxes and hidden fields...

Comment: you don't need different renderers. The reRender just indicates which components it should 'reload'

Comment: "JSF only supports one renderkit (renderkitId) per page (f:view). Because Tobago has it's own renderkitId you cannot use any non-Tobago components that need a renderer." <-- Just found this info within the MyFaces/Tobago FAQ. And as far as I know RichFaces components uses their own renderers.

Comment: pff, if that's true, then my advice is to drop Tobago completely and go for some more reasonable component framework.

Comment: It's a pitty, that I'm not the one to decide this :/ Customers... But thanks a lot for the idea nevertheless!

Comment: anyway, give the above code a try, we might be misunderstanding the statement in the docs.